# Any material that states Betazoids came from Earth?

Tags: star-trek, betazoid

[Betazoids](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Betazoid), on the surface look human, but further research into the species suggests otherwise.

Were they humans born on Earth, and at some point left for another planet to evolve into what the humans call Betazoids?

Comment: Did you read the article in the wiki (Memory Alpha) that you linked in your post?

Comment: @Loki - Yes, it says they are from a planet call Betazed, but this doesn't meant they at one part started off on Earth and evolved on Betazed I didn't ask for canon sources, so maybe the books mention something?

Comment: They don't look human.   They tend to have black irises.

Comment: @BasementJoe - My answer actually demonstrates that they evolved on Betazed and have ancient ancestry on that planet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is no reason to think they share any ancestral roots with humans.

Betazoids come from Betazed, and while they outwardly resemble humans, they have unique physiology and abilities.  They are their own species, distinct from humanity.

In Star Trek, the predominant form that intelligent life takes is that of a bipedal humanoid.  Further, virtually all intelligent species (despite a wide variety of phenotypes, genotypes, and planets of origin) can interbreed more-or-less freely.

This includes Vulcans, who do not even have iron in their blood (copper serve the same purpose for them)!

This is due to something that was revealed in the TNG episode [The Chase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chase_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)):

> All the species within the Star Trek galaxy's Alpha and Beta quadrants were genetically engineered (to a degree) by a predecesor race, who 'seeded' planets with DNA so that they would eventually produce intelligent humanoid lifeforms.

Comment: +1 on the answer, but can you explain why someone would down vote the question?

Comment: @BasementJoe - I don't know for sure, but it's possible that someone might consider this question 'too basic' given that it's a basic background question.  It could be because someone really likes Deanna and doesn't like the implication that her mother's species is 'just' a subset of humans.  Honestly, I don't know.  I think it's a fine question though.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the question asked. Just because most of the races in the Alpha quadrant share common ancestry doesn't mean that humans and Betazed are/aren't related to each other. You could use the same argument to claim that Romulans and Vulcans aren't related despite this being palpably untrue

Comment: @Valorum - yes, you could.  Except for the fact that there is literally NO evidence which supports Betazoids being descended from humans, while the connection between Romulans and Vulcans has been well-established.  So while you could 'support' that with this argument, it could easily be disproved.  No such counter-evidence exists for this case.

Comment: @Jeff - Given that you think it's a fine question, and that I've give you the checkmark, would you mind setting the -1 to 0?

Comment: @BasementJoe - It's actually considered bad form to request upvotes on SE sites.  Besides, I upvoted the question before your request.

Answer (score 10):

### Betazoids evolved from amphibians on their home-planet of Betazed.

We have proof-positive that the Betazed people originated from a different evolutionary tree in [TNG: Genesis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Genesis_(episode)) in which Deanna Troi becomes infected with [a disease that causes her to regress to an earlier evolutionary form](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Barclay%27s_Protomorphosis_Syndrome).

[image]

While Picard (and other pure-blooded humans) revert to primates, Troi reverts to an amphibian, indicating that her people's earliest progenitors were presumably amphibious lizards rather than lemur-like mammalians.

> **DATA:** *That is correct. In her case, the DNA is creating **an amphibious lifeform which became extinct over fifty million years ago.***

Note that [fifty million years ago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_human_evolution), Earth humans weren't lizards/amphibians. In that time period we were proto-hominids.

In the EU Novel [Typhon Pact: Seize the Fire](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Seize_the_Fire), Troi describes the form she reverted to as an *ancient Betazed creature*

> "I take it you're not describing a typical bad hair day."
>   "It was more like the worst hair day imaginable," Troi said. **"A mutant virus turned me into an ancient Betazoid amphibian.** But maybe we ought to put the coiffure conversation aside. We're supposed to be passing ourselves off as natives, remember?"

---

For the record, in the Paramount-licenced [Star Trek Star Charts](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Star_Charts) we learn that the Betazed people have had limited warp capability for thousands of years so if anything, we should be asking whether humans on Earth are wayward Betazed wanderers and not the other way around.

[image]

Comment: While you are correct, I would say this is at most weak evidence.  Recall that not all humans 'regressed' into the *same* creatures, and Picard actually 'devolved' into a primate that was very separate from the hominid line (a form of lemur, I believe) which is a relatively close cousin of humans but definitely not something that ever evolved into a hominid.

Comment: @Jeff - Data indicated that the DNA that resulted in her regression was 50M years old. During that time period, human evolution had long since progressed beyond those kinds of creatures. As backup, I've also included a link which mentions (in an EU novel) that the amphibian was one that was of ancient Betazed origin. I'm not sure how much more conclusive we're gonna get on this one

Comment: Good answer. But, I wonder why Deanna reverted to a proto-Betazoid instead of the virus acting on her human dna. Maybe the use of half-human / half-other is overdone and gets in the way of story lines like this.

Comment: @Verdan - Presumably because the Betazed DNA is more dominant in some fashion

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but Data says that the amphibious lifeform became extinct 50 M years ago, not that Betazeds evolved from them 50 M years ago. The evolutionary split could have happened 100 M years ago, or 1 B years ago, with both species continuing to survive until 50 M years ago. Doesn't really affect your answer, but figured it was worth mentioning.

Comment: @KevinWorkman - I suppose you could read it that way. It doesn't seem to be what he's implying, nor does the EU novel back that up

Comment: @Jeff - Data says "I believe you will also de-evolve into some form of early primate. Possibly similar to a lemur, or pygmy marmoset." *Similar* could mean a last common ancestor of us and lemurs or the LCA of us and New World monkeys (which include marmosets). As for why Barclay became a giant spider, well, https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/61xije/sttng_in_the_s7_episode_genesis_data_and_picard/dfib8nq

Answer (score 0):

There is no indication that Betazoids are descended from humans. Betazed is repeatedly described as the homeworld of the Betazoid species, there are no references made to them being a human subspecies, and they are treated as a different race with an entirely different history and culture. While they look almost indistinguishable from humans and the two species can interbreed, this is easily explained by the fact that nearly all humanoid species in the Milky Way galaxy, including Humans, Klingons, Romulans, and Cardassians were the result of seeding by a progenitor race of humanoid beings, as seen in the TNG episode *The Chase*.